# Alternate expression for a Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

The exercise goes as follows: Represent $f(x)=\sin(x)$ as the sum of its Taylor series centered at $\pi/3$.

This is how I solved the exercise:
$$
f(x) = f(\pi/3) +\frac{f'(\pi/3)}{1!}(x-\pi/3)+\frac{f''(\pi/3)}{2!}(x-\pi/3)^2+\frac{f'''(\pi/3)}{3!}(x-\pi/3)^3+\cdots
$$
$$
= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+ \frac{1}{2\cdot 1!} (x-\pi/3)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 2!}(x-\pi/3)^2 - \frac{1}{2\cdot 3!}(x-\pi/3)^3+\cdots
$$

Rearranging all terms in two groups, the ones with $\sqrt(3)/2$ as a common factor and $1/2$, we have:
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 2!}(x-\pi/3)^2 +\cdots\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot 1!} (x-\pi/3)- \frac{1}{2\cdot 3!}(x-\pi/3)^3+\cdots\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(1+ -\frac{1}{ 2!}(x-\pi/3)^2 +\cdots\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1!} (x-\pi/3)- \frac{1}{ 3!}(x-\pi/3)^3+\cdots\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(x-\pi/3)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(x-\pi/3)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$

It seemed simple enough to find the pattern that led to the answer.

To corroborate that my answer was correct, I typed the problem in WolframAlpha and I found this elegant, succinct and perplexing answer:
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n\cos(1/6(\pi +3n\pi)) (x-\pi/3)^n}{n!}
$$

Does anyone know how this alternate answer was obtained?
Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you use angle-addition we have
$$
\cos(\pi/6 + n\pi/2) = \cos(\pi/6)\cos(n\pi/2) +\sin(\pi/6)\sin(n\pi/2)
$$Then look at what happens if you take $n$ modulo $4$; can you take it from here?